# c- pointer from integer without cast

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a extended binary tree in a main function with finite number of nodes.

The problem is that compliler keeps showing

> error: incopatible types when assigning to type 'struct node' from type 'int'

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NULLitem (-1)

typedef struct node * link;
struct node {   
    int item;
    link l;
    link r;
}


link NEW (int item, link l, link r)
{
        link x = malloc(sizeof * x);
        x->item = item;
        x->l = l;
        x->r = r;
        return x;
}

void Tprint(link p, int indent)
{
    int i;
    if (p!=NULL){
        Tprint(p->r, indent+4);
        for(i=0; i<indent; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("%d\n", p->item);
        Tprint(p->l,indent+4);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    link T, M, N, z, Root;
    z = NEW(NULLitem,NULL,NULL);
    Root->item = 6;
    T = NEW(5, NULL, NULL);
    Root->l = T;

    M = NEW(7, NULL, NULL);
    Root->r = M;
    M->l= NEW(NULLitem, NULL, NULL);
    M->r= NEW(9,z,z);

    N = NEW(2,z,z);
    T->l = N;
    T->r = NEW(NULLitem,NULL, NULL);

    Tprint(Root,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the errors? Please edit your question, to show those places as e.g. comments in the code.

Comment: Also, you never make `Root` point anywhere, leading to *undefined behavior* whenever you dereference that pointer.

Comment: `struct node {   int item;
                link l;
                link r;
        }` <-- add `;`

Comment: Fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 12 (the compiler says it all), "Pointer from integer without cast" is a warning which will disappear if you correct the error on line 12 of your program.

You actually forgot the semicolon here at:

```
struct node {   int item;
                link l;
                link r;
        }
```

Write a semicolon after the braces, your program should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NULLitem (-1)

typedef struct node * link;
struct node {   int item;
                link l;
                link r;
        };


link NEW (int item, link l, link r){
        link x = malloc(sizeof * x);
        x->item = item;
        x->l = l;
        x->r = r;
        return x;
}


void Tprint(link p, int indent){
        int i;
        if (p!=NULL){
                Tprint(p->r, indent+4);
                for(i=0; i<indent; i++)
                        printf(" ");
                printf("%d\n", p->item);
                Tprint(p->l,indent+4);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
   link T, M, N, z, Root;
    z = NEW(NULLitem,NULL,NULL);
    Root->item = 6;
   T = NEW(5, NULL, NULL);
     Root->l = T;

   M = NEW(7, NULL, NULL);
   Root->r = M;
    M->l= NEW(NULLitem, NULL, NULL);
    M->r= NEW(9,z,z);

   N = NEW(2,z,z);
    T->l = N;
    T->r = NEW(NULLitem,NULL, NULL);

    Tprint(Root,3);
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be like:

> ```
>            -1
>        9
>            -1
>    7
>        -1    6
>        -1
>    5
>            -1
>        2
>            -1
> ```

Runs without any errors.

Comment: `Root->item = 6;` -->  `Root = NEW(6, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Thank you very much